# Geometry that I made a bogus proof and needs correction

Tags: geometry, vectors

> As shown below $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, and let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. If $D\in CB,G\in CA$ and $E,F$ are the foot of $D,G$ to $AB$ respectively so that $AB=2EF$. Prove that $\angle DMG=\frac\pi 2$.
> [image: Graph]

Now my problem is that I found I can strengthen this argument to what’s clearly too strong and incorrect so I surely made a bogus proof. (\boldsymbol used for vectors)

Because $$BE=\frac{\boldsymbol{BD}\cdot\boldsymbol{BA}}{BA},AF=\frac{\boldsymbol{AG}\cdot\boldsymbol{AB}}{AB}$$
So $$\begin{align*}BE+AF=\frac 1 2AB\\\rightarrow(\boldsymbol{BD}-\boldsymbol{AG})\boldsymbol{BA}=\frac 1 2AB^2=\frac1 2\boldsymbol{BA}^2 \\\rightarrow\boldsymbol{BD}-\boldsymbol{AG}=\frac1 2\boldsymbol{BA}=\boldsymbol{BM}\end{align*}$$

So $$\boldsymbol{DM}=\boldsymbol{GA}$$. This is clearly wrong. So find the mistake please?

Comment: Um open the edit to see the graph link cuz I don’t know why it didn’t show itself.

Comment: This can't possibly be true, becase $\angle DMG=$ varies as $M$ moves along $EF$. You must have left out a condition.

Comment: @TonyK Nonono, confirmed with $\text{GeoGebra}$. There’s no problom with this and this is a problem from a book.

Comment: So how do you refute my comment?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to tell us that $M$ is the mid-point of$AB$?

Comment: @youthdoo We sometimes get problems from a book which are incorrect

Comment: Yes, I see now from your $\frac1 2\boldsymbol{BA}=\boldsymbol{BM}$ that you did forget. Please be more careful in future.

Comment: You go from $(\vec{BD}-\vec{AG})\cdot \vec{BA}=\frac12 \vec{BA}^2\;[=\frac12 \vec{BA}\cdot \vec{BA}]$ to $\vec{BD}-\vec{AG}=\frac12 \vec{BA}$, effectively cancelling vector $\vec{BA}$ from the dot product equation. Dot products don't work like that. The relation $u\cdot w=v\cdot w$ is equivalent to $(u-v)\cdot w=0$, which does not require $u=v$.